# Silent Push Notification for Application Update - iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to inform the user that if there is an app update in App Store.
Can I use silent push notification feature for this? Is there any impacts?

Comment: You can use silent notifications to trigger background fetch e.g. and of course you can also send normal push notifications to the user to inform about any case. But - why do you want to inform the user about the update?  From the UX perspective this is not a good design. I would delete such a "spam" app. Auto update is on for default - so mostly users have the update immediately.

Comment: Thanks orschaef. But what if user turns off Auto Update. How we should inform the user about app update?

Comment: In general I would suggest to write a good app, so you don't have to remind the user that there is an update. Because if the user loves the App he/she will check automatically for updates. This is something I really do not see in Apps - and like I said - I would delete an app that only sends spam notifications like "Update me!" - "Open the app and use me!". Provide useful notifications - then you will automatically get what you want.

Comment: Thats a good point. Thanks again

Comment: If you think that this would be a right answer (what I think it is) maybe I can compose it as so? Would you accept it then? This may be good for other users...

Comment: Why would you send a silent notification? If you send a silent notification to the app then how is the app going to notify the user if the app is in the background? The only way would be for it to post a local notification, but then you could just have sent a foreground push instead. If your app is in the foreground then no need for a push at all, the app can call home to the server to see if there is an update. Therefore what's the point of a silent notification? Apart from as everybody else has said it seems a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Sausage. it seems silent push notification is not a right way to do this. I am just exploring list of options for showing app update.

Comment: @Orschaef. Yes, please compose. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments section:

Silent push notifications can not inform the user about any update - but you could send a normal push notification.

**BUT**: I think this would be a bad decision. From the user perspective this looks like a "spam" app - and I would delete such an app that shouts "Update me!".
Auto Update is on per default - so the majority of your users would just get the app update.

I suggest to write a good app so you don't have to notify the user about an update at all. He or she will check for updates automatically if this is a piece of software he/she likes. Choose wisely what you send in push notifications.

Maybe you can think about informing the user about the new feature of your update **AFTERWARDS** (when the user starts the app). This signals "Ah - there is something new - let's explore!".